# How to load my postgis points into leaflet

Tags: javascript, php, html, leaflet, postgis

I took a udemy class for leaflet.  Loading the course data worked great, but now trying to duplicate the code with my PostGIS data and it's not working.

I took a course on Udemy for Leaflet.  I was able to reproduce what the instructor did using the data he provided.  I was able to reproduce a table using my data from my PostGIS database, similar to what the instructor taught in another video.  Now, I haven't been able to recreate a similar map with my data.  I have posted this at the Udemy course site, but no response from anyone.  Although the instructed recommended stackoverflow for help in one of his videos, so here I am.

```
From HTML Page
23 <script>
24 var queryLayer;
25 var mymap = L.map('mapdiv')
26 mymap.setView([33.86585, -118.08240], 15);
27        
28 var backgroundLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
29 mymap.addLayer(backgroundLayer);
30
31 $("#filterSubmit").click(function(){
32     $.ajax({
33         url:'query_permit_ajax.php',
34         type:'POST',
35         data:{
36             date_recd: $("#date_recd").val(),
37             act_stat: $("#act_stat").val()
38            },
39         success: function(response){
40             if (queryLayer) {
41                 mymap.removeLayer(queryLayer);
42            }
43              queryLayer=L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(response)).addTo(mymap);
44              mymap.fitBounds(queryLayer.getBounds());
45             }
46         });
47     });
48 </script>

From PHP Page
1 <?php
2     $dr=$_POST['date_recd'];
3     $as=$_POST['act_stat'];
4     $db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5433;dbname=webmap101;','postgres','123456');
5     $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT id, item_no, permit_no, scope_work, proj_site, st_from, st_to, date_recd, rev_stat, act_stat, ret_date, draft_inv, pay_recd, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom, 5) FROM permit_loc WHERE act_stat> :as");
6 $params = ["as"=>$as];
7 $sql->execute($params);
8    
9 $features=[];
10 while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
11     $feature=['type'=>"Feature"];
12     $feature['geometry']=json_decode($row['geom']);
13     unset($row['geom']);
14     $feature['properties']=$row;
15     array_push($features,$feature);
16 }
17     $featureCollection=['type'=>'FeatureCollection','features'=>$features];
18    echo json_encode($featureCollection);
19 ?>
```

The points should pop up on my leaflet map.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to know: is your problem on your server's side (php) or your browser's side (javascript) ?

Check your php error log and your browser developer console (you can also check the network on the browser)

You can also generate some debug information to know what the data looks like.

`console.log(JSON.parse(response))` to see your ajax response data

`error_log(json_encode($featureCollection)` to see what your php is sending

Depending on the result, you'll know if your problem is on your server's side or your browser's side.

Comment: So, it turns out my data was not in the correct projection and plotting some place else.  Sorry for the long delay in response.  I do this on the side to learn more.  Thank you for your help.